# Como adicionar link em uma tabstrip do Kendo UI?

Tags: html, html5, kendo-ui

Estou com uma aplicação onde existem 5 abas, é obrigatório que elas sejam seguidas na sequencia. Quando é iniciada a página a primeira aba ocupada o espaço todo da janela (fica parecendo que não são abas), quando é clicado no botão continuar, a `aba1` é escondida e da o lugar para `aba2`, que também ocupa toda a janela. O que eu preciso é que, quando a `aba1` se esconder e `aba2` apareça fique um link no canto referenciando a `aba1`, sem ser outra aba. Estou usando `Kendo UI`. Código:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("Guia_TabStrip")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border:none;" })
.Animation(a =>
{
    a.Enable(true);
    a.Open(o => o.Fade(FadeDirection.In).Duration(AnimationDuration.Fast));
})
.Items(items =>
{
    items.Add()
        .Text("01 - DADOS EMISSÃO")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Guia_01_DadosEmissao_Tab" })
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(@<text> <br />

       //restante do código

items.Add()
    .Text("02 - ENVOLVIDOS")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Guia_02envolvidos_Tab" })
    .Selected(false)
    .Content(@<text>   <br />
```

O que eu quero saber é se tem como colocar um link naquele .Text("02 - ENVOLVIDOS") para referenciar a `aba1` que é 01 - Dados de Emissão (eu tenho os links prontos, só preciso saber como se coloca ali dentro)

Comment: Esse comportamento de esconder abas é uma implementação sua ou nativa do Kendo ?

Comment: Implementação, feito em javascript

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
 items.Add()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Guia_01_DadosEmissao_Tab" })
        .Content(@<text><a href="link.html" onclick="guia_tabstrip.select(0); aba_envolvidos.hide(); aba_dados.show()">01 - DADOS EMISSÃO</a></text>);

 items.Add()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Guia_02_Envolvidos_Tab" })
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(@<text><a href="link.html" onclick="guia_tabstrip.select(0); aba_envolvidos.hide(); aba_dados.show()">02 - ENVOLVIDOS</a></text>);
```

Comment: Não Funcionou.    <a href="#" onClick="guia_tabstrip.select(0); aba_envolvidos.hide(); aba_dados.show();" class="">Voltar Dados Emissão</a>  esse é o meu link

Comment: ele imprimiu o html do <A /> na grid?

Comment: Nem chegou a abrir a página, deu um erro na linha que eu criei com o .Content

Comment: tenta fazer assim:

Comment: o .Content() espera qual tipo de parâmetro? (string, int..)

Comment: items.Add()
        .Text("01 - DADOS EMISSÃO")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Guia_01_DadosEmissao_Tab" })
        .Selected(true)
        .Content(@<text> <a href="#"> Foo </a> </text>)

Comment: Pra você entender melhor http://imageshack.com/a/img850/1760/40uc.png http://imageshack.com/a/img541/8467/ulsy.png

Comment: Quase funcionou este que você me passou, problema que o link não ficou exatamente na aba, ficou logo a abaixo dela

Comment: Procure editar alterando ou adicionando o novo exemplo de código. Fica muito difícil ler e acompanhar pelos comentários. E ao @ThiagoAlex coloque as imagens e esclarecimentos na pergunta para outras pessoas poderem te ajudar.

Comment: Conseguiu fazer ai ??

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/tabstrip/overview#handling-kendo-ui-tabstrip-events

Comment: Decidi ocultar as tabs e faze-las na mão, estava se tornando algo muito complexo, pelo menos para mim que sou iniciante. Adicionei outra div e fui colocando e ocultando as tabs quando preciso. Vou ler este artigo e ver se funciona de outra maneira.

Comment: @ThiagoAlex resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Resolvi, mas de outra forma sem ser com kendo, fiz tudo com atributos de html, css e javascrip na mão mesmo. Estamos estudando uma maneira de fazer com kendo, mas por enquanto só foi possível desta maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o [fórum da Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/forums/renaming-hiding-tabs), você pode alterar o título da aba via javascript da seguinte maneira:

```
$($("#tabstrip").data("kendoTabStrip").items()[tab_index_variable])
    .children()[0].innerText = "New Tab Title";
```

Adaptando ao seu requisito, eu diria que uma possível solução seria assim:

```
$(function () {
    var linkHtml2 = "<a href='xpto.com.br'>Link</a>";
    $($("#Guia_TabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip").items()[2])
        .children()[0].innerHTML = linkHtml + "02 - ENVOLVIDOS";

    // código para cada uma das outras abas
    // ...

});
```